# System cannot find the directory of current running process in “C:\Windows\Fonts” folder

Tags: windows

I have a file running from this directory:
`C:\Windows\Fonts\com4.{208d2c60-3aea-1069-a2d7-08002b30309d}`, When I want to open that directory it says `System cannot find the specified path` and when I want to delete the file inside that folder with PowerShell, it says Access Denied!
How can I delete the file and folder?

Comment: Are you sure it says "specific" and not "specified"?

Comment: specified sorry

Comment: Its a system folder, so the "access is denied" needs admin rights. When trying to modify anything that requires admin, it first checks you are allowed and will return an error before even attempting the command or to see if it exists or not, so that bit of info isn't really relevant to the question.

Comment: my user is administrator and I have admin rights but its a Virus and uses half of my cpu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COM4` is a special reserved 'DOS Device' name. Files or Folders with these types of names can not be created or accessed by normal means. Also the appended string `.{208d2c60-3aea-1069-a2d7-08002b30309d}` is the Shell CLSID for `My Network Places`, It will cause the folder with this appended sting to appear as such in Windows Explorer to hide the contents.

It can be renamed to a normal name so it can be be accessed afterwards. But since it is located in the system folder `C:\Windows\Fonts`, Administrative rights are needed for doing so.

In an elevated Command Prompt (CMD.EXE) this command can be used to rename the folder

`ren "\\.\C:\Windows\Fonts\com4.{208d2c60-3aea-1069-a2d7-08002b30309d}" "NewName"`

But for the rename to be successful, any program(Most probably a malware as you mentioned) that is running from this folder must be terminated beforehand.

A malware can have other protections mechanisms to prevent you from doing any of the above actions or easily undo what you have done, So you should protect your system with an updated Antivirus product and keep it updated until it is detected and removed completely.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how it created that file there?

Comment: I want to know how the file is created and how can I run files inside of it. I tried but its not running. When the file is running, I cant rename the folder.